# What use have editing self permission in linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, edit, self

I am trying to learn some stuffs about permissions in Linux, but I am not sure I get the use of the first permission which is associated to current user.
I watched some tutorials but I didn't find my answer.

I suppose permissions in Linux are used when multiple persons with different roles are accessing a server, to give the proper permission to each of them.

So you have the command:

```
chmod 755 <filename>
```

"7" - You are setting your own permission here? what use have this? you can edit this permission anytime I suppose... . I guess "user" it is referring to directory/file owner.

"5" (1st) - I guess here you are set permission for the rest of the group and it is useful when you have more users in the same group.

"5" (2nd) - I think this is a little to much generic. For example you are hosting 2 web app on the same machine or 2 different systems on the same machine and there are dedicated teams which are administrating these. Wouldn't be proper to set permission for individual group on each location?

Sorry if my question is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain to the best of my little knowledge:

- On linux, a user(or group) is primarily(if not entirely) defined by its permissions to do stuff (access files, execute commands) on the machine.
- Everything a user "does" on the machine is actually done by a process(es) executing on user's behalf.
- A process may not always do what it is supposed to do, either intentionally or due to a bug. This is where your user's permissions come into play.

For example, If you give yourself all the permissions. Then a process executing with your permissions may in worst case could do anything from stealing your passwords to accidently(or maliciously) wiping off your hard drive.

On a side note, this is precisely why running in root is considered a security risk and is the whole point behind creating an unprivileged user.

Hope I answered your question.